# How to Consume a Restful Service in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, rest

What are my options to consume a RESTful service using the .Net framework? When is WCF(using the WebChannelFactory) more preferable to HttpClient?

Answer (score 16):

Microsoft`s newest HTTP library is here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http and I have a blog post showing how to use it [here](http://www.bizcoder.com/2012/01/09/httpclient-it-lives-and-it-is-glorious/).

You would never want to use WebChannelFactory against a RESTful service.  The coupling generated by WebChannelFactory defeats the point of REST.

Comment: Your blog link is dead, can you fix it?

Comment: @dcp Sorry about that.

Comment: You'll want to see this package too: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/

Comment: Mentioned Nuget package is deprecated. It is better to add a link to this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http

Comment: @AndriyBuday Updated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Check out [restsharp](http://restsharp.org/). I haven't used it, but am looking into it for consuming our own REST services.

Comment: How did this work out? Is restsharp a good choice? It looks super convenient and easy to use.

Comment: Yes, I really like using it.

Answer (score 3):

The hammock project makes it very easy to consume RESTful services, you can use it to easily create the required http requests you need:

https://github.com/danielcrenna/hammock

Answer (score 2):

I think WCF is preferable whenever you want the abstraction it provides.

WCF provides an abstraction over the specific messaging and communication protocols being employed. Even only considering a RESTful scenario, you can more easily adapt to different message formats (XML, JSON, HTML).

WCF also provides configuration mechanisms, extensibility points, and instrumentation.

Comment: For anyone reading this now: WCF is essentially dead. Should you feel like looking into it, know that's it's a complete departure from REST, and should only be used if you really know you need it.

Comment: @TheMonarch you seem to be under the impression that WCF is tied to a specific set of protocols. Judging by your comment you most likely associate WCF with various SOA technologies like XML and SOAP. WCF is in fact a communication framework designed to be extended for different protocols. It is true that most of the out-of-the-box extensions are related to SOA (a consequence of the time when WCF was released) but extensions can be written/exist for REST (HTTP / JSON), protocol buffers, gRPC, or even a custom protocol.

Answer (score 2):

There are few different ways of consuming REST services in .NET:

- Plain .NET HTTP [request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx)
- WCF mechanisms
- [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) (recommended, [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http))
- Other libraries (RestSharp, Hammock, etc.)

I've wrote a [blog post](http://andriybuday.com/2012/12/consuming-rest-services-in-net.html) that demonstrates first three options.

As of consuming through WCF or HttpClient I think it makes sense to read this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming) to understand the potential of REST services. When you consume a REST service via WCF you cannot use all that power.

Answer (score 0):

This is one technique of calling or consuming rest webservice in asp.net c#

```
var client  = new RestClient("url"); 
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "type=password& user_id=test@gmail.com",ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just released a REST client here today. You can download the Git repo to see the samples.
https://bitbucket.org/MelbourneDeveloper/restclient-.net

- Open Source. (MIT License)
- Markup language agnostic. (Supports JSON, SOAP and other markup languages)
- Use strong types with REST.
- Supports Android, iOS, Windows 10, Windows 10 Phone, Silverlight, .NET, .NET Core.
- Incredibly simple.
- Async friendly (uses async, await keywords).

> When is WCF(using the WebChannelFactory) more preferable to
>   HttpClient?

That is a very loaded question. WCF is a very large collection of technologies that allow you to communicate with a number of different protocols, authentication methods, and so on. It is very configurable, but REST is simple and supported by nearly all technologies available. If you write a REST service, chances are that nearly any app could consume it. Really, the question is about who your target audience is.