# Call WCF From CodeBehind Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making wcf calls and getting back data in my application via this javascript code..

```
function setCurrentResponseValue(response) {

    var applicationData = null;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ClientService.svc/REST/SetCurrentResponseValue",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ response: response }),
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (msg) {

            applicationData = msg;

        },
        error: 'An Error'
    });

    return applicationData;

}
```

I need to set session variables my svc file uses from C# code behind. How do I call a method in my svc file from code behind instead the ajax call above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of very similar questions already on SO. This has perhaps the best answers: [How to Consume a Restful Service in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883656/how-to-consume-a-restful-service-in-net)

@Darrel Miller's answer is probably the most useful there, with a link to his blog post showing how to use HttpClient to consume REST data: http://www.bizcoder.com/index.php/2012/01/09/httpclient-it-lives-and-it-is-glorious/

(The fact that the service is WCF is largely irrelevant to the client if you're using loose coupling against REST).