# How to call restful webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

How do i connect to any restful `webservice` using `C#`

I have the below information about the `webservice`

The `BASE_URL` is the `URL` at which the `WebServices` are hosted. This `BASE_URL` is then followed by the required `GROUP` name, and then the required `METHOD` name.

For example,

```
BASE_URL = https://www.abcd.com/ws/

GROUP = transaction

METHOD = createTransaction
```

This would give a complete URL of :

```
https://www.abcd.com/ws/transaction/createTransaction
```

Every invocation must contain the following parameters (as POST variables) :

```
Name

username 

password 

pin
```

Please help me with some link to achieve the coding.

Comment: Instead of dublicating your question, try to improve it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591308/calling-webservice-with-base-url

Comment: Dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883656/how-to-consume-a-restful-service-in-net ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) class.

```
 static async void Main()
    {
        try 
           {
      // Create a New HttpClient object.
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

      HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://www.abcd.com/ws/transaction/createTransaction");
      response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
      string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      // Above three lines can be replaced with new helper method in following line 
      // string body = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

      Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
    }  
    catch(HttpRequestException e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!"); 
      Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
    }
  }
```

This is not complete, you have to pass your parameters to PostAsync method in HttpContent object format.

Answer (score 0):

**This is one technique of calling or consuming rest webservice in asp.net c#**

```
var client = new RestClient("url");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded","type=password&user_id=test@gmail.com",ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: request.AddHeader is optional part you can ignore it.